# Flag history looks incorrect

Tags: bug

I feel that my flag history is not showing correct information. I've flagged many posts however only a few of them are appearing and those also when I navigate to, do not show my name.

Am I wrong in understanding the flag history process?

Comment: If you're talking about close votes, you do not cast flags for those after 3k, and you can find your close vote history in the votes tab of your profile.

Comment: I think you are right. I got confused. Thanks @animuson